# Difference between vh and %

Tags: css

Why In the code below if I change
(height from vh to %) following change occur:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url(background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

At banners height 100vh
[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhUcX.png)

At banners height 100%
[At 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEZIh.png)

Why there is difference, as the 100% means the 100 percent of container. And here container is div(class banner) And it occupy the full page.

Is it possible to make same webpage with 100% height of banner?

Comment: CSS without the HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please get into the habit of providing a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, when you ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

VH gives height as screen size

100% returns the height of the found parent element.

```css
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}


header{
  height:100px;
}
.banner2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)), url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="banner"></div>
 <header>
 <div class="banner2"></div>  
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between % and vh :-

height: 100vh;

Example: If your device's viewport size is 1366 x 786px, the element considers the height as "786px" which means it occupies the full viewport height of the screen.

height: 100%;

Example: This depends on the parent element. It occupies the full height of the parent element.

Hope this helps. @AmirSaudagar